# Create pdf file with multi language in php

Tags: php, unicode, hindi

I am currently using **mpdf** to create .pdf file using PHP script. But it only works with English language. But further I have requirements for multiple languages.

For multiple languages, I am using UTF-8 fonts. In browser that words looks proper but in PDF files display only squares.

Or please anyone guide me if I'm using specific font then what I have to do? [ex. I'm using "Mangal" font for Hindi language]

Is there any solution?

Thank you in advance. I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Can you  give code you tried or a link for it? I may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

**These is for c Panel (PHP)**

1.first things is update your mPDF latest version like 8.0.And if your are using cpanel just install composer.

2.Give your directory path location for mPDF like (include "your directory path to file path/)

3.Add this line your file $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
                           $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;

4.Finally mpdf automatically detect which you are using languages in your databases.

5.if you are using PhpMyadmin databases give your table which description name want to print pdf ..just go your table and select column to change Collation utf8_general_ci..

6.if you are give 5.step .will not to be print ?????????.

Answer (score 0):

used tcpdf to export pdf in Indian language